# Ticket support infinite loop issue

Tags: ticket-system, whm

Suppose our client, Bob, has the following email address: bob@isyouruncle.com. He has setup an auto responder on this address, so if you send a mail to it, it automatically replies with:

```
Thank you for contacting me, Bob, your uncle. I love you.
```

Now, suppose we have a helpdesk ticket system with the following address: helpdesk@needhelp.com. Everytime someone sends an email address, it replies with:

```
Your ticket number is ABCDEF. Thank you! :-) Bla bla bla.
```

Now, suppose bob sends a mail to helpdesk@needhelp.com. Here's what will happen:

```
Bob sends a mail to helpdesk@needhelp.com
Helpdesk replies to bob@isyouruncle.com with ticket nr
Bob's auto responder replies to thank for the mail that it received
Helpdesk replies to bob@isyouruncle.com with ticket nr
Bob's auto responder replies to thank for the mail that it received
Helpdesk replies to bob@isyouruncle.com with ticket nr
Bob's auto responder replies to thank for the mail that it received
Helpdesk replies to bob@isyouruncle.com with ticket nr
Bob's auto responder replies to thank for the mail that it received
Helpdesk replies to bob@isyouruncle.com with ticket nr
Bob's auto responder replies to thank for the mail that it received
```

Notice the infinite loop? So... how do ticket systems deal with this?

I use WHMCS, and I have no idea how to set this up to avoid infinite loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the reply address on the email your helpdesk sends to something that just deletes everything it receives (or anyway doesn't send an autoreply).

So

> `Bob sends a mail to helpdesk@needhelp.com`
>
> `Helpdesk replies to bob@isyouruncle.com with ticket nr`
>
> `Bob's auto responder replies to thank for the mail that it received` (to blackhole@needhelp.com)

The end.

(This is why such things often have a message saying "don't reply to this email".)